# how to check if a string contain any of operator in java

Tags: java, operators

i wanted to check if string contains operand

```
    char m='\0';
    char match[]={'(',')','=',';','{','}','[',']','+','- 
            ','*','/','&','!','%','^','|','<','>'};                                                                            
    for(int i =0; i<code.length(); i++)
    {
        m=code.charAt(i);
        for(int j=0;j<match.length;j++){
            if(m==match[j]){
                o++;
                            }
                     }
           }
```

The above code can get the total no of operand use in string, but is there some easy way.

Comment: do you want just to chek for at least one existance or count all occurrences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to do the same thing with one line of code.

```
if(code.matches("[,/!%<>]"))  sysout("There is Operator");
```

Place all the operators you need in between brackets.

I couldn't test above code now, but you may have to escape some operators using a back slash.

Comment: Corrected the slash, Thanks for that. But what is this putting them in a character class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression character class to find any of a list of characters, e.g.:

```
// (See note below about these -++--++
//                              ||  ||
//                              vv  vv
if (stringToTest.match("[()=;{}[\\]+\\-*/&!%^|<>']")) {
    // It has at least one of them
}
```

The `[` and `]` indicate a character class. Within that, you have to escape `]` (because otherwise it looks like the end of the character class) with a backslash, and since backslashes are special in string literals, you need two. Similarly, you have to escape `-` within a character class as well (unless it's the first char, but it's easier just to remember to do it). I've highlighted those with tickmarks above.

Docs:

- [`String#match`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [`java.util.regex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use these functions

String.contains() - which checks if the string contains a specified sequence of char values
String.indexOf() - which returns the index within the string of the first occurence of the specified character or substring (there are 4 variations of this method)

instead of checking each char in array.

Answer (score 1):

If you store "match" as a hash table, your lookups will be more efficient:

```
HashSet<Character> match = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList('(',')','=',';','{','}','[',']','+','-','*','/','&','!','%','^','|','<','>');

for(int i =0; i < code.length(); i++) {

    if (match.contains(code.charAt(i)) {
        o++;
    }
}
```